# Riemann integrability of piece-wise function

Tags: real-analysis, integration

$$f:[0,1] \to \mathbb{R}, f(x) = \begin{cases} 1 & \text{if } \exists n \in \mathbb{N} \ \text{s.t} \ \ x = \frac{1}{n}\\ 0 & \text{otherwise}\\ \end{cases}$$ 
Prove $f$ is Riemann integrable.

My proof:
Let $\epsilon > 0$ be given and define $V_{\epsilon} = [0,\frac{\epsilon}{2}]$. On $[0,1] \setminus V_{\epsilon}$ $f$ has a finite number of discontinuities so there is a partition $P_{1}$ of $[0,1] \setminus V_{\epsilon}$ such that $U(f,P_1) < \frac{\epsilon}{2}$  (for any partition $L(f,P) = 0)$. Let $P_2$ be a partiton of $V_{\epsilon}$ then $U(f,P_2) \leq \displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^{n} \Delta x_i$ as on each subinterval $\displaystyle \sup_{[x_{i-1},x_i]}f(x) \leq 1$, so $U(f,P_2) \leq \frac{\epsilon}{2}$. Finally Take $P = P_1 \cup P_2$, then $U(f,P) - L(f,P) = U(f,P) < \epsilon$. 
Is this a sufficient proof? Is there anything that I'm missing? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: FYI, this is similar to the ruler function, also called [Thomae's function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thomae%27s_function) and quite a few other names.

Comment: The proof is correct. Definitely, the main point of the problem is how you did it. If you want to be extra thorough, you could be more explicit in explaining the construction that leads to $Uf,P_1)\leq \frac{\epsilon}{2}$.